# textContent error in react app when i use animejs for letter animation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, animation, typeerror, anime.js

I try to use animejs in my project. For instance, this is my code:

```js
import React from 'react';
import './blog.css';
import anime from 'animejs';

const textWrapper = document.querySelector('.ml2');
textWrapper.innerHTML = textWrapper.textContent.replace(/\S/g, "<span class='letter'>$&</span>");

anime
    .timeline({ loop: true })
    .add({
        targets: '.ml2 .letter',
        scale: [4, 1],
        opacity: [0, 1],
        translateZ: 0,
        easing: 'easeOutExpo',
        duration: 950,
        delay: (el, i) => 70 * i,
    })
    .add({
        targets: '.ml2',
        opacity: 0,
        duration: 1000,
        easing: 'easeOutExpo',
        delay: 1000,
    });

const Blog = () => {
return(
  <div className="blog">
     <h1 class="m12">Hello World</h1>
  </div>
 );
};
```

but i get the textContent error like this:

[image]

and this is my console:

[image]

I don't understand what is happening. Should i download some package or something?
Please help me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: try `textWrapper.textContent= textWrapper.textContent.replace(/\S/g, "<span class='letter'>$&</span>");`

Comment: no, it doesn't working @DoanVanThang

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this problem above has to do with typing.

```
const textWrapper = document.querySelector('.ml2');
```

Here you are selecting an element with the class **ml2**, which you are using throughout the whole JS code.

But in you HTML

```
<div className="blog">
   <h1 class="m12">Hello World</h1>
</div>
```

You are using **m12** as class for the `h1` element. So there is a **"1"** instead of an  **"l"** in your class name.

Some general advice use more semantic name for your classes.
If you want have a look at some *more complex* naming conventions like [OOCSS](https://www.keycdn.com/blog/oocss)

Oh yeah and don't freak out most of the time it was a typing error :)